# Spring does not find file in resources

Tags: java, spring, file

i have following line

```
File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:calculation.csv");
```

and i also tried

```
File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:/calculation.csv");
```

but both will throw an error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [calculation.csv] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not exist
```

but i do have calculation.csv in by resources folder..
why is this?

I need to read file from resources folder, and it should also work in server enviroment

EDIT:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("calculation.csv").getFile());
```

works just as fine, so not at all..

EDIT2:
tried with folder.. i have both calculation.csv and csv/calculation.csv in my resources folder now..

none of the above work, with /csv/ added.

what kind of path does this thing want?!

EDIT3:

aaand

```
File file = new ClassPathResource("calculation.csv").getFile();
```

is also no go, what even is this..

Comment: Where are you running your code relative to the file?

Comment: relative to file? file should be inside the resources folder inside the jar? @MikeTung

Comment: everything in `src/main/resources` is part of the classpath and isn't a file resource. You cannot use `File` to read something from inside the classpath. You have to directly use `getInputStream` instead of `getFile`... A file does have to be a physical file and not a resource inside an archive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Loading file (as FILE) wont work. You must use it as resource. Files inside JAR will not work as file anyway. This is also what your "check" code shows.

`classLoader.getResource("calculation.csv")` works, because you are using classloader to get resource, not filesystem to get file (which is what File api does). It could work, if you would deal with non packed application. Once you pack your app into JAR, file path will be like `your/path/to/jar.jar!someResource` - note `!` mark (and that is what you would see as well). So basicly it will return `File` instance, you that you wont be able to use anyway, as file system has no access to it.

You could alternatively try to extract it first with `ResourceUtiuls#extractJarFileURL(URL jarUrl)` and then use extracted file.

I think, that in most cases `Class#getResourceAsStream` is the way to go and I think that it should fit your needs as well to read content of resource.